# Regex not working properly in all cases

Tags: java, regex

I am using a regex to get word from string its working fine in alphanumeric case but return wrong answer if we are used arithmetic operator.

```
 Matcher oMatcher;
 Pattern oPattern;


 String key = "a++";
 oPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + key + "\\b");
 oMatcher = oPattern.matcher("max winzer® build-a-chair cocktailsessel »luisa« in runder form, zum selbstgestalten");
 if (oMatcher.find()) {
     System.out.println("True");
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to match exactly?  `a++` in a pattern looks wrong with the pluses not escaped.

Comment: a++ is a code for something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape any potential regex special characters in `key` with `Pattern.quote`:

```
oPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(key) + "\\b");
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, i am exactly want this.